# How to get back Exchange history in my iPhone XS

Tags: iphone, exchange

I have deleted an Exchange account from my iPhone. It was corporate email address. There was a lot of emails. I don't work for the company any longer.

How can I get all those emails back or get them as a history? Do those emails all live on corporate servers, so that no message is being saved locally?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but I believe those emails are the property of your previous employer.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft Exchange server all information is stored on the server itself, the only thing that is stored on your iOS device are the message headers and a few of the most recent messages that you have recently read.

Once you delete an email account (of any kind) from the iPhone the message headers and messages stored there are deleted. I suppose that if you have a backup of your device from before that time on your Mac you could use one of the many iOS backup extraction apps might be able to get some of that info off of the backup, assuming it is not encrypted.

And like IconDaemon pointed out you have no legal right to the messages without the permission of your former employer. The best way to get needed info out of emails is to contact them and request the specific messages you need.